# JVMCI JIT Compiler (Graal Compiler)

Tags: java, jvm, compiler-optimization, jit, graalvm

I have a Spring application that utilizes JavaScript scripts through ScriptEngine (the engine provided by graalvm https://docs.oracle.com/en/graalvm/enterprise/20/docs/reference-manual/js/ScriptEngine/). I am considering enabling the Graal JIT compiler using JVMCI, but I'm unsure about how this would impact my application's performance and whether it would be used exclusively for ScriptEngine or influence the entire application.

how I added the Graal JIT Compiler

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.10</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy</id>
                                <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifactItems>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>org.graalvm.compiler</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
                                            <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
                                            <type>jar</type>
                                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                            <destFileName>compiler.jar</destFileName>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>org.graalvm.compiler</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>compiler-management</artifactId>
                                            <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
                                            <type>jar</type>
                                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                            <destFileName>compiler-management.jar</destFileName>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>org.graalvm.truffle</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>truffle-api</artifactId>
                                            <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
                                            <type>jar</type>
                                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                            <destFileName>truffle-api.jar</destFileName>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>org.graalvm.sdk</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>graal-sdk</artifactId>
                                            <version>${graalvm.version}</version>
                                            <type>jar</type>
                                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                            <destFileName>graal-sdk.jar</destFileName>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                    </artifactItems>
                                    <outputDirectory>${compiler.dir}</outputDirectory>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

```
<configuration>
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument>--module-path</argument>
                                        <!-- automatically creates the modulepath using all project dependencies, also adding the project build directory -->
                                        <modulepath/>
                                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                                        <!-- automatically creates the classpath using all project dependencies, also adding the project build directory -->
                                        <classpath/>
                                        <argument>-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions</argument>
                                        <argument>-XX:+EnableJVMCI</argument>
                                        <argument>-XX:-UseJVMCICompiler</argument>
                                        <argument>--upgrade-module-path=${compiler.dir}/compiler.jar${path.separator}${compiler.dir}/compiler-management.jar</argument>
                                        <argument>org.benchmark.demo.Main</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </configuration>
```

My primary concerns are:

1. If I enable the JIT compiler for Graal via JVMCI, will it exclusively enhance the performance of the ScriptEngine, or will it have broader implications on the entire application's execution?
2. Is the Graal JIT compiler through JVMCI considered a top-tier choice within the JVM ecosystem?

Additionally, I would like to optimize the ScriptEngine's performance with Graal JIT without affecting other components of the application. Are there any strategies or suggestions for achieving this?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What have you tried so far, what results do you see and what do you expect instead? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What VM version do you run? (`java -version`)

Comment: I'm work with




java 17.0.8 2023-07-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-211)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-211, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: You are running OpenJDK HotSpot JVM, not GraalVM. Why not using GraalVM instead, which has everything you need out of the box?

Comment: I'm running OpenJDK HotSpot JVM and using a a JVMCI (Graal JIT compiler)



something like this 
https://github.com/graalvm/graal-js-jdk11-maven-demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Graal JIT to execute this code should not give you performance penalties, rather the opposite. You should just make sure you are indeed executing this code JIT compiled and not just interpreted, which would be much slower.

Our general recommendation is to use the GraalVM JDK, which will give you the best performance and warmup. If for some reason you don’t want to use Graal JIT, you can always disable it with `-XX:-UseJVMCICompiler` which effectively gives you an OpenJDK setup.

Your use case should become simpler with the changes we are making in the next release, it will be released next week.

Comment: So in the next release, still need to use Graal JDK ? Or someting else ? Another API?